# jQuery - Open new window and enter value to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find myself struggling with a seemingly basic concept and have sunk several hours with no results. I've submitted this question to google countless times and I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have an html file that has a div. When clicked, it should open a new window. Once the window is open, "Test Search" should be placed in the input box. I would then like to have the program "submit" the search.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(searchButton).click(function() {
    var googleWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
        var searchBox = document.getElementById("gbqfq");
        searchBox.value = "Test Search";
    });
});
```

My JS fiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Citanaf/s903nww9/40/

I would appreciate anyone who solves this gives a short note on what their solution is doing/what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: I don't believe that JavaScript can affect other tabs in your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set values in the new window. Try this

```
window.open("http://www.google.com?q=Test%20Search",'_blank');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s903nww9/41/

I noticed that the search parameter was entered but not submitted. This works, at least for now.

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/?q=Test%20Search&gws_rd=ssl#q=Test+Search",'_blank');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into it now. Seems I need to reevaluate my objectives.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your script is running in your current window not the new window with the google website. That's a good thing, security reasons.

In line 4, you aren't getting any element because you don't have that element in your current window. That's the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. I need to go about my problem in a different way then.